# Word in different color in middle of string XNA

Tags: xna, monogame, fonts

Is it possible to use different font colors for the same string, for example, when buying a weapon in CoD AW Exo Zombies:

[image]

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want a different font, or only a different color like your example?  Those are very different requirements, because you can draw one spritefont in any color at any time.

Comment: I thought I may need more SpriteFont files, but I don't. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply render the pieces of colored text individually, specifying any color you want for each piece. In order to get the positioning correct, you can use the [SpriteFont.MeasureString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464128.aspx) method.

```
string[] stringPieces = { "Hel", "lo, ", "wor", "ld!" };
Color[] colors = { Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Yellow, Color.Red };

Vector2 startPosition = new Vector2(100, 100);
Vector2 offset = Vector2.Zero;
SpriteFont font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("myFont");

spriteBatch.Begin();

//Loop through each piece of the string, 
//drawing each with a different color,
//and moving the offset forward by its measured length
for( int x = 0; x < stringPieces.Length; x++)
{
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, stringPieces[x], startPosition + offset, colors[x]);
    offset.X += font.MeasureString(stringPieces[x]).X; 
}

spriteBatch.End();
```

Code based on [BTownTKD's GameDev.net post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/546193-c-xna-1-string-in-multiple-colors-/#entry4519905).

If you're going to do this often, I would recommend writing a basic parser to make using this easier.

Example syntax: "{{blue}}Hel{{green}}lo, {{yellow}}wor{{red}}ld!"

- Split on `{{` to get `["blue}}Hel"], ["green}}lo, "], ["yellow}}wor"], ["red}}ld!"]`.
- Loop through each result and split on `}}` to get a combination of color and text e.g. `["blue", "Hel"]`.
- Render string "Hel" using Color.Blue. Continue.